# Microsoft BotFramework - Suggested Cards

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

So I'm trying to use suggested cards to give a nicer button input for a WebChat bot unless anyone has any other suggestions? Have currently got the builder.prompts working.

but my issue is, using the following example:

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .text("Thank you for expressing interest in our premium golf shirt! What color of shirt would you like?")
    .suggestedActions(
        builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                session, [
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=green", "Green"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=blue", "Blue"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=red", "Red")
                ]
            ));
session.send(msg);
```

How do I actually get the response? It auto-writes the users value into the chat (which I'm trying to avoid) Have tried using response.entity etc but nothing returns it.

The documentation says "When the user taps one of the suggested actions, the bot will receive a message from the user that contains the **value** of the corresponding action."

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things for this.

First, `imBack` basically stands for IM back, or instant message back. It will send the response to the conversation. You want `postBack`, which will hide the response, but bear in mind that for some channels `postBack` will map to `imBack`, so you'll have to do some investigating. For the Bot Emulator, `postBack` will hide the response.

For the second thing, if you watch your console when the bot is running, you'll see that the bot will try to route to that *value* in the `imBack` method. You'll want to capture this through a dialog or intent. Here's a small, probably inefficient example:

```
intents.matches(/^suggest/i, [(session) => {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .text("Thank you for expressing interest in our premium golf shirt! What color of shirt would you like?")
        .suggestedActions(
            builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session, [
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "productId=1&color=green", "Green"),
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "productId=1&color=blue", "Blue"),
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "productId=1&color=red", "Red")
                    ]
                ));
        session.send(msg);
}]);

intents.matches(/^productId/i, [
    (session, args, next) => {
        console.log(args);
    }
]);
```

In the example above that is using intent dialogs, I can access the *value* from the `matched` array that is in the args of the second `intent.matches` method call.

There are other ways you can do this, but this is a quick-and-dirty example.